# What is this syntax "SOME_VAR=/some/path python pythonFile.py" in Python command line?

Tags: python, command-line

I came across a Python command line like [this](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/builtin_datasets.html#expected-dataset-structure-for-cityscapes):

> CITYSCAPES_DATASET=/path/to/abovementioned/cityscapes python cityscapesscripts/preparation/createTrainIdLabelImgs.py

I tried to read the python docs [on command line](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables), but I couldn't find out what that command line grammar is.

Looks like it's about setting some Environment variable(or Shell variable), but I'm not sure.

What does it mean, and what is the exact grammar?

Comment: Consult the `man` page for your shell (e.g. bash, zsh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with python.  In general,

```
var=value cmd
```

invokes `cmd` with `var` set to `value` in its environment.  It is a simple way to set an environment variable for a single command.

The specifics are given in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01:

A "simple command" is a sequence of optional variable assignments and redirections, in any sequence, optionally followed by words and redirections, terminated by a control operator.

When a given simple command is required to be executed (that is, when any conditional construct such as an AND-OR list or a case statement has not bypassed the simple command), the following expansions, assignments, and redirections shall all be performed from the beginning of the command text to the end:

The words that are recognized as variable assignments or redirections according to Shell Grammar Rules are saved for processing in steps 3 and 4.

The words that are not variable assignments or redirections shall be expanded. If any fields remain following their expansion, the first field shall be considered the command name and remaining fields are the arguments for the command.

Redirections shall be performed as described in Redirection.

Each variable assignment shall be expanded for tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal prior to assigning the value.

Comment: ... set an environment variable _just for the environment of that command_.